# partial styling for textblock text programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-8

newbie in wp development, used to do this in visual studio web express, can I do the similar attempt in wp?

str = "abc **ddd** efg"
mylabel.text = str

basically i want to bold partial text in a static string, and display it on label/textblock, any idea? tks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextBlock` has an [`Inlines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.inlines.aspx) property. You can add formatted text to that collection:

```
mylabel.Inlines.Clear();            
mylabel.Inlines.Add("abc");
mylabel.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text="ddd", FontWeight=FontWeights.Bold });
mylabel.Inlines.Add("efg");
```